# glDrawElements is called with VERTEX_ARRAY client state disabled

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm trying to draw a sphere in OpenGL ES 2.0+ on Android, and I'm seeing the following error in Logcat:

> glDrawElements is called with VERTEX_ARRAY client state disabled!

I looked at the documentation for this call and I can't see anything I might be doing wrong. From the error it sounds like I'm missing some setup somewhere.

Here's my VertexBuffer class where I'm doing the setup:

```
public class VertexBuffer {

    private final int mBufferId;

    public VertexBuffer(float[] vertexData) {
        // Allocate a buffer
        final int[] buffers = new int[1];
        glGenBuffers(buffers.length, buffers, 0);
        if (buffers[0] == 0) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not create a new VBO");
        }
        mBufferId = buffers[0];

        // Bind to the buffer
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mBufferId);

        // Transfer data to native memory
        FloatBuffer vertexArray = ByteBuffer
            .allocateDirect(vertexData.length * BYTES_PER_FLOAT)
            .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())
            .asFloatBuffer()
            .put(vertexData);
        vertexArray.position(0);

        // Transfer data from native memory to the GPU buffer
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexArray.capacity() * BYTES_PER_FLOAT, vertexArray, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        // IMPORTANT: Unbind from the buffer when we are done with it
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    }

    public void setVertexAttribPointer(int dataOffset, int attributeLocation, int componentCount, int stride) {
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mBufferId);
        glVertexAttribPointer(attributeLocation, componentCount, GL_FLOAT, false, stride, dataOffset);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(attributeLocation);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please show the code where you draw?

Comment: The `GL_VERTEX_ARRAY` client state is not even part of GLES 2.0, it is only present in the fixed function pipeline of GLES 1.x. If you are using an ES 2.0 context, this error does not make any sense at all - your driver may be confused.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I forgot to set the context to ES 2.0 on my surface. I set it and now the error went away.

Answer (score 9):

Add:

```
setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
```